# Use Django Variables to Make new divs

Tags: python, django

my code is simple so far.

```
        <div class="wow fadeInUp content-works"> 
            <span class="text-subtitle" style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: 300; color: #333">Previous Orders</span>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                        <div class="card-content white-text">
                          <span class="card-title">Order #1</span>
                          <p>Day - Ammount - Item</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                          <a href="#">Link to somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to store this code in a django variable, and make the day, ammount, and item variables?

Then, when django is updated, and another entry is added, another div is created with a different transaction.

Any suggestions?

PS. I'm using materializecss to make this look like a card (http://materializecss.com/cards.html)

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Do you just want a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list with day, amount and item tuples and use a for loop to generate the divs in the template.

```
{% for day, amount, item in data %}
    <div class="wow fadeInUp content-works"> 
        <span class="text-subtitle" style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: 300; color: #333">Previous Orders</span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m6">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">Order #1</span>
                        <p>{{day}} - {{amount}} - {{item}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a href="#">Link to somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

where the data is like:

```
data = [('A day', 'Some item', 'Some data'), ('Another day', 'Some other item', 'Some other data')]`
```

Comment: If you are creating the context there to render the template, then yes.

Comment: what do you mean by context? @emre

Comment: For rendering this template, you should provide it a context which has the `data` in it. Something like this: `context = {'data': data}`. To render this you should write `return render(request, 'template_name.html', context)` to your view. You can find a better explanation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/ . I definitely recommend reading it :)

Comment: and if i have multiple data variables, and i want to call only the one of the person who signed in, how would i accomplish this?

ex) emre = [('A day', 'Some item', 'Some data')]
      abhishek = [('A day', 'Some item', 'Some data')]

i have the name of the person who is logged in stored under user.first_name, so how would i do this?

Comment: Then, you should create the context only for that person. Like `context={'data': emre}` . Getting the correct list given the user's first name depends on your implementation actually (Depends on how and where you store the data in your codebase, db etc).

Comment: Thanks so much! @emre